# Android Custom Toolbar is not clickable

Tags: android, user-interface, android-xml

I created a custom toolbar that has a "cancel" button on the left and "post" button on the write, a standard format that most social media apps use.

This is a portion of my xml code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    style="@style/BarTheme"
    app:theme="@style/BarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:title="Lend"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_item_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:text="CANCEL"></Button>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_item_post"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:text="NEW ITEM"></TextView>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/themeBlue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="POST"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

This is my style.xml code:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/themeBlue</item>
</style>

<style name="BarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/themeBlue</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Now on the activity, I decided to at least try the "cancel" button, but it's not working. I tried to debug, but it doesn't even go into the function so I think it's not even clickable.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add_item_cancel:
            Intent goBackIntent = new Intent(AddItemActivity.this, ListingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(goBackIntent);

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: can you post your activity code

Answer (score 0):

if you want to override onClick android says, that there is no corresponding method onClick to override. This just means, there is no global onClick, so nothing to override.

Add this to your cancel

```
android:onClick="cancel"
```

and than in the code:

```
public void cancel(View v){
//test if works        
Log.d(TAG, "cancel: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will believe that you are using the `onClickListener` implementation as part of your activity in which you call the button, but you need to register a callback to be invoked when the button is clicked.

Add the following lines of code to your `onCreate` function in the activity where your button is located:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedValues) {
    ...
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_item_cancel);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Implement the `OnClickListener` callback:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add_item_cancel:
            // do something when the button is clicked
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Android Developers: Input events overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events#java)
- [setOnContextClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html?hl=es-419#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you registered `onclick`  listener on cancel button in `onCreate` or where you initialize the cancel button.

Like below:

```
addItemCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Next implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface like below:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

.............

}
```

Then override the onclick method like below:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.add_item_cancel:
                onBackPressed();
                break;
        }
    }
```

If you used the click listener on only one button or view then you can use the below code for click:

```
addItemCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

For this you don't need to implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

I hope it helps you.